# How to handle UITableViewCell IDs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a model which I am passing to my `UITableViewCell` from my `UITableView` class as following

```
this.Source = new MyTableSource(ListOfItems);
```

My ITEM Model have only two values

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Where my `UITableViewSource` is the Following

```
public class AllSource : UITableViewSource
{
    List<ITEM> ITEMS = new List<ITEM>();        
    public AllSource(List<ITEM> _items)
    {
        ITEMS = _items;           
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell =  tableView.DequeueReusableCell("AllCell") as AllCell;

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new AllCell();
            var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib(AllCell.Key, cell, null);
            cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as AllCell;
        }
        var LINK = ITEMS[indexPath.Row];           
        cell.BindCell(LINK);            
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return HomeDisplay.Count;
    }
}
```

and my `cell.BindCell(LINK)` is the following

```
public void BindCell(ITEM link)
{
 TitleText.Text = Link.Title;
}
```

I am also using 'RowSelected' as following

```
 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{                              
 tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
}
```

This works OK but

> I would like to attach a unique ID which is in `string` format to the
>   `Cell` so when my `RowSelected` is triggered I get that `string` ID to
>   uniquly identify the ID of selected item (Not the indexPath)?

Initially, I thought just put a HIDDEN LABEL in but that does not seem to be a right choice.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I consider `public string Id { get; set; }` from your Model to be unique `Id`, then you can get this like following:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) 
{ 
    tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

    //Here you can get your Id of selected row
    string selectedId = ITEMS[indexPath.Row].Id;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why i didn't think of that :) Thank ou so much